# ServiceStack.OrmLite: How to Insert SYSDATE

Tags: oracle11g, ormlite-servicestack

I am using OrmLite Oracle in C#. I want to insert current sysdate instead of DateTime.Now in column having date data type, i.e. taking the date at the database end and not the calling code. How can I do this?